# Why is block designed to be allocated on the stack unless copied?

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

Why has Apple designed block to be allocated on the stack unless copied? What's the benefit for such behavior? Why not just make it behave like a regular NSObject - alloc-init it and it goes on the heap automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The reason why blocks are placed on the stack by default is speed. In
>   the common case where the lifetime of the block is less than that of
>   the stack function that contains it, this is a very good optimisation.

http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/how-blocks-are-implemented-and.html

Comment: You mean block for synchronous dispatch?

Comment: @Boon that question doesn't make sense.

Comment: I meant to ask - what block will have lifetime shorter than the function that contains it, a block used by dispatch_sync?

Comment: @Boon The block on the stack has the same lifetime as any local stack variable. For example, if you create a block variable inside a `while` cycle, `for` cycle or inside an `if-else` branch, the life of the block ends when the local scope (e.g. the `while {}` scope) ends.

Comment: @Boon: for example, a block that you use in `-enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:`